# getbounds with Google maps autocomplete ? Not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, maps, google-maps-autocomplete

I'm using google maps autocomplete for user to input the place. after that I do call `getPlace()`, from autocomplete object.

It shows the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object ((13.0284176, 80.23215529999993), (13.0501581,            80.2641701)) has no method 'lat'
>        here is my code:

**My code:**

```js
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(g,autoc_options);
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete,'place_changed',function() {
  var g=autocomplete.getPlace();
  var h=new google.maps.LatLngBounds(g.geometry.viewport);
  var l=new google.maps.LatLng(g.geometry.viewport.getSouthWest());
  alert(l.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `LatLng` to create a LatLng object with an existing LatLng object.

You can reference the southwest coordinates simply changing your code to:

```
var l =  g.geometry.viewport.getSouthWest();
```

This is because `getSouthWest()` already returns a `LatLng` object.